# How to add new field to existing django model postgres

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-rest-framework

Let's suppose I have the following model:

```
class Test(models.Model):
   field_one = models.CharField(max_length=80)
```

Now, we have created 2-3 Model objects with `field_one` field.

```
p1 = Test(field_one="Object1")
p1.save()
p2 = Test(field_one="Object2")
p2.save()
```

Later, I realised that I need to add another field `field_two` to my `Test` model.

```
class Test(models.Model):
   field_one = models.CharField(max_length=80)
   field_two = models.IntegerField(default=3)
```

- Now, Doing `makemigrations` & `migrate`
  and running server.

which will prompt the following error

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column mainapp_test.field_two does not exist
```

- I understand that this error occurs due to my `2` existing objects in `PostGresDB` doesn't have `field_two` column.

Is there any effective way to add `field_two` column to my existing objects with some default value? or How to solve this problem?

Django Version: 2.0
Django ORM DB: PostGresql

Comment: can you show the relevant part migration file generated by `makemigrations`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add a field to an existing model, you must either provide a default value in the code, or set it to null/blank = True, or provide a one-off default while migrating.

Since you **are** providing a default in the code, the migration should run without issues. At least from experience, I've added several BooleanFields with `default=False` to my existing model with thousands of entries, and I never got a ProgrammingError.

Have you tried shutting down the Postgres backend before running `makemigrations` and `migrate`? I would think Django would do this but that's the only thing I can think of. Also, obviously, shut down the Django server if it's still running.

Comment: You are right, but i did messed but with my migrations , had to delete a column  of django_migrations to get it fixed.